# Printed in named buffer with text matching pattern getting coloured

Tags: buffers, colors, print

I have the following function that prints some text in the `*Messages*` buffer.  I want to change this so the text gets printed to a named buffer instead.

```
(defconst tika-outlshow-details
  "
Show-Entry
  Show the body directly following this heading.

Show-Heading
  Show the current heading and move to its end.\n")


(defun tika-outl-navaid (actm)
  "TODO"

  (interactive
   (list
    (let ( (cseq '("Show" "Hide")) )
      (completing-read "Vista: " cseq nil t "Hide"))))

  (cond
   ((equal actm "Hide")
      (message "%s" tika-outlhide-details))
   ((equal actm "Show")
      (message "%s" tika-outlshow-details))) )
```

Comment: One question per question please.